# Error in resize the image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to resize my image equal to my source image so that i can further multiply or perform different other function for that i write the following code

```
Mat out = imread ("E:\\img1.jpg");
Mat img12=imread("D:\\image12");
img12.convertTo(img12 , out.type());
resize(img12,img12,out.size(),0,0,1);
```

But when i run this program in show me the error

```
Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0 ) in unknown function
```

Where i am going wrong as i change the type too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What format is `image12`, why has it no file ending? According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread), it has to be one of the following:

> - Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
> - JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Notes section)
> - JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Notes section)
> - Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Notes section)
> - Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm (always supported)
> - Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
> - TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Notes section)

Furthermore the documentation states, that when an image cannot be read, `imread` returns an empty matrix. This could be the case in your problem.